# How to have a template template parameter take a numeric value?

Tags: c++, templates

I want to have a template parameter accept a template that has a numeric template argument.

This example maybe overly simplified, but I'd like something like this:

```
template <int X>
struct XX
{
  static const int x = X;
};

template<typename TT, TT V, template<V> TX>
void fnx(TX<V> x)
{
  static_assert(V == TX::x, "IMPOSSIBLE!");
}

void fny()
{
  fnx(XX<1>())
}
```

I must not be understanding the syntax for this, as it must be possible.  How would I accomplish this?

Comment: what's `TT` supposed to be? how would the compiler deduce its type when calling `fnx` in `fny`? can you give more context of your problem you are trying to solve with this approach?

Comment: @m.s. `int`, presumably.

Comment: Syntactically you need `template<V> class TX`. But that's not the whole problem.

Comment: this works, but I do not know if this is what you want: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/28c88002c409a543

Comment: @m.s., Going one step simpler, you can call it with just `<int>`.

Comment: @m.s. Are you sure that works? I get `'fnx': no matching function overload` and `invalid explicit template argument(s) for 'void fnx(TX<V>)'`

Comment: @user2296177 well clang compiled it, as you can see at the live example at coliru

Comment: @m.s. Must be some VC++2015 thing, then.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just fixing up your syntax a bit - since the template template parameter is improperly specified, we'd end up with something like this:

```
template <typename T, template <T > class Z, T Value>
//                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
void foo(Z<Value> x) { }
```

However, the compiler can't deduce `T` here - it's a non-deduced context. You'd have to explicitly provide it:

```
foo<int>(XX<1>{});
```

That's pretty annoying. I cannot even write a type trait such that `non_type_t<XX<1>>` is `int` (where that type trait does actual introspection on the type, not something that trivially returns `int`).

---

There is a proposal to improve this process ([P0127](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0127r1.html)) by amending the non-deduced context-ness of non-type template arguments.

Comment: Sounds like the `template<auto V>` proposal, up for vote in Oulu.

Comment: @chris Yep, found it.

Comment: Ah, yes.  The parameter type is a type, not a value.  Thanks.  Too bad about the auto deduction failure though. :(

Answer (score 2):

Your declaration of `fnx` needs some work, and the type `TT` can't be deduced at the call site.

```
template<typename TT, TT V, template<TT> class TX>
void fnx(TX<V> x)
{
  static_assert(V == TX<V>::x, "IMPOSSIBLE!");
}

void fny()
{
  fnx<int>(XX<1>());
}
```

Working example: https://ideone.com/57PsCA